# Problem with understanding the question in probability.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having trouble understanding the wording of this question:

> A spinner can land in any of four positions, A, B, C, and D, with equal probability. The spinner is used twice, and the position is noted each time. Let the random variable Y denote the number of positions on which the spinner did not land.

I don't understand what it means when the variable denotes the number of positions that the spinner did not land on. For example, how would I go about finding $P(Y=2)$? This means there are two positions the spinner did not land on, but I'm confused about what this means exactly.

Comment: For example it could land on A both times (it is spun twice). In that case Y=3 because there are 3 positions it did *not* land on. Or if say it landed on A and then on B it would be Y=2, 2 numbers not landed on.

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you! I wasn't thinking about each spin individually, I was thinking of them together. I.e: AA AB, etc, so I was confused what the problem meant when it described positions the spinner didn't land on. I understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For example, if it landed on both A and B, then there are two positions (namely, C and D,) on which it did not land, so Y = 2. The probability that Y = 2 is 3/4, and the probability that Y = 3 is 1/4.